# how to log found files before deleting them

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Is there a way to log a file name before deleting it?
I'm doing a png to jpg conversion and need to delete the old png file but I like to log it first. ... or if I could log what's been found.

```
#!/bin/bash

PIXPATH=~/test-pix/

find $PIXPATH -type f -name '*.png' -exec mogrify -format jpg {} \;

rm -rf $PIXPATH*.png > list-of-pngs.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
PIXPATH=~/test-pix/
find "$PIXPATH" -type f -name '*.png' \
  -exec mogrify -format jpg {} \; \
  -delete \
  -print \
  > list-of-pngs.txt
```

I've splitted it in several lines to make it more clear, but you can do it in a single line.

I've also done some corrections and additions to ensure that the scripts works as expected if for example $PIXPATH contains spaces. Also, you don't *rm -r* on *files*.

Comment: Nice. You could replace `-exec rm -f {} \;` with the simpler `-delete`, and instead of `-exec echo {} >> list-of-pngs.txt \;` you could just add a `-print` and redirect the entire output of `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple things for each file found, for example:

- Multiple `-exec ... \;`
- `-print` to print the path
- `-delete` to delete

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

PIXPATH=~/test-pix/

find "$PIXPATH" -type f -name '*.png' -exec mogrify -format jpg {} \; \
  -print -delete | tee list-of-pngs.txt
```

I split to two lines to make it more clear, but you can do it in a single line.

I used `tee` so that you see what is being written, but you could replace with a simple redirection with `>`.